# Activity, service or fragment?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-fragments, alarmmanager

I am writing an app which needs to monitor the current battery level, after every 15 minutes or so, continuously.

To try and make it relatively efficient, currently, I am using AlarmManager.RTC, with PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, and an setInexactRepeating of 15 minutes.

This will be a sort of battery drain % monitor app, so I need this app to be always logging what it finds every 15 minutes, even after boot. It checks for battery level, if the phone is charging and some other things such as if wifi is enabled, if screen is on etc. and then writes these values in sqllite for later analysis.

So which one would be the best way to go about it:

1. AlarmManager on an activity in a BroadcastReceiver in the
   activity
2. AlarmManager and a service
3. Headless fragment

Or a better option is suited?

Answer (score 0):

service - for background work, receiver for device boot event(where you should start service), and activity for showing results.. and Timer for timer taks?
do you realy need AlarmManager for this task? )

Comment: isn't having a service always running bad? i thought an alarmmanager can just request the phone to be active when i need to take the measurements and so might be more efficient, than having some thing always running?